# watir-webdriver functions do not execute as a script but works on the interactive ruby shell

Tags: firefox, watir, watir-webdriver, irb

I am trying to write automated scripts for a web application using watir.  There is a slider in the UI, which has a range from 1 to 11. It is a horizontal div.  So, if you press the right arrow key, the number increments by 1, and if you press a left arrow key the number decrements. My problem is when I try to execute the following statements in irb individually, the `send_keys` function works fine, but as soon as I move it to a ruby script, it does not execute the send_keys.

```
assert($b.div(:class, "position").text == "2")
$b.div(:class, "scroll").wait_until_present
$b.div(:class, "scroll").click
$b.div(:class, "scroll").send_keys(:arrow_right)
assert($b.div(:class, "position").text == "3")
```

The `send_keys(:arrow_right)` works if I run separately in irb.  When trying to run through a script file, it does not give me any error and remains on the same number, and it just says "Failed assertion, no message given."

The `b.div(:class, "scroll").click` is to activate the div on which the the right arrow key is to be pressed.

I'm using watir-webdriver 0.6.2, Firefox 18.0.2, Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned `b.div(:class, "scroll").click` is to activate the div on which the key is to be pressed, 
There might be possibilities that this is taking a while to activate the div, and when you are doing that in IRB that is getting proper time to load as it takes time to execute another line, but when you are doing that in script and executing you are performing `send_keys` action immediately after clicking on the div, and execution not getting proper time to activate that Div.

Try to give a pause/delay in your script for a while and then try to perform `send_keys`.

To give a pause/delay you can use `sleep(time_period)`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much! It helps a lot but there is kind of an alternate pattern going on, once the script runs, fine after adding `sleep 5` but again the next instant I run without making a single change to the script, it gives me an error `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError: Element is no longer attached to the DOM` on the line `$b.div(:class, "scroll").click`. So, it runs fine once and the next moment it does not.

Comment: Are you running your script in a loop? or simply running your script twice?

Comment: I am simply running the script twice.

Comment: that is a weird error..  I wonder if the UI does some destroy-re-create on that scroll div.   Custom controls like that can be a big pain sometimes.. They can also turn out to be very unfriendly to touch based browsing

Comment: I did kind of a survey, I get this error alternatively for running the script more than once, only if I give `sleep 5`. As soon as I changed it to `sleep 2` everything runs perfectly fine, I don't know the reason for this but the longer the pause the error comes more often.

Comment: This is weird and funny because it has no logic with sleep time period. May be some problem with gem installed in your local machine, well you try to generate more occurrence of the error mean while I'll try to figure out why this is behaving so weird :)